# Telerik RadWizard assembly reference does not exist in Telerik.Web.UI

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I have to use Telerik RadWizard in my project. I have included `Telerik.Web.UI` and `Telerik.Web.UI.Skins` references. The error I'm getting on including RadWizard is here:

> The type or namespace name 'RadWizard' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Telerik.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Upto my search I've got to know it was released in UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2014 (version 2014.3.1024). I'm using .Net version 3.5. Is there something to do with .net version? Which version is best suited for this?

Comment: In vs, use the update wizard to update your libraries references. Check if the references are right. or add a explicit reference to them.

Comment: Many thanks. The problem is solved by upgrading version of telerik UI. The RadWizard control is available in Q3 2014 and all next versions.